# grep from file (-f) using regex

Tags: regex, grep

I'm trying to use `grep -f A.txt B.txt` to find lines matching a regular expression. When I do this, however, it matches every line in file B and I don't understand why.

A.txt:

```
'[Bb]lop'
```

B.txt:

```
blop
Blop
doop
bop
```

output of `grep -f A.txt B.txt`

```
blop
Blop
doop
bop
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Remove quotes from `A.txt` and make it `[Bb]lop`

Comment: I cannot replicate this behavior

Comment: I can not reproduce it, even with quotes!

Comment: Interesting. When I remove the quotes, it outputs everything, but the lines that match are colored red. Does anyone know how to output only matching lines? I dunno why it doesn't work for you guys! I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 with the default grep.

Comment: Got it! I had a newline at the end of the pattern file. The empty line apparently matched all lines, making it output every line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there's a newline at the end of the pattern matching file, grep will match that empty line to everything, returning every line in the file in question.